# Momentjs shows evaluate one day less

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, datepicker, momentjs

I am using `Momentjs` to evaluate the selected date in `react-datetimepicker`. But it evaluate one day less than the selected day. Following is the code snippet I am using to evaluate selected date.

```
var selectedDateArr = ['2016','02','04']
var yr = parseInt(selectedDateArr[0]), mnth = parseInt(selectedDateArr[1] - 1), day = parseInt(selectedDateArr[2]);
var changedDt = moment([yr,mnth,day]);
console.log('Changed Date >>> ',changedDt);
```

It gives following object as a console result in firefox.

```
{ _isAMomentObject: true, _i: Date 2016-01-03T18:30:00.000Z, _isUTC: false, _pf: Object, _locale: Object, _d: Date 2016-01-03T18:30:00.000Z }
```

I have tried to convert the date to UTC but still no luck.

Note: In chrome it shows the correct evaluation but while supplying it as `minDate` it breaks; again evaluate one day less than selected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the values shown in your question, I'm guessing you're in India, which means your local timezone (IST) is GMT+0530 (five and a half hours ahead of GMT). When you [give Moment an array](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/array/), you're giving it *local time values*, and any values you don't supply are defaulted to 0 — in your case, since you don't provide any time values, that's midnight. Midnight on Jan 4th in GMT+0530 is 18:30 on Jan 3rd in UTC.

If you want the values treated as UTC, use [`moment.utc(...)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/):

```
var changedDt = moment.utc([hr,mnth,day]);
```

Comment: Thanks, it did the trick and I am now getting the correct date. I have tried with `moment([yr,mnth,day]).utc()` but it didn't work. I will do the through testing and will accept answer.

Comment: @KunalShewale - This is answer is correct, but also be sure you are using one of the output functions, such as `format`.  Do not use any of the underscore-prefixed fields of a moment object directly.

Comment: @MattJohnson - Thanks for the suggestion. I am using the same in my current scenario

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
var changedDt = moment.tz([yr,mnth,day], timezone).
```

For example I am in India so my timeZone will be "Asia/Kolkata".

Answer (score 0):

```
moment.unix(timestamp).utc().format('MM/DD/YYYY')
moment.utc(date).format('MM/DD/YYYY')
```

if we pass it will work for me it works.